# Split City, State, Zip from one column into 3 separate, also add dash to 9 digit zips

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a table column that contains City, State, and Zip.  I would like to split this into 3 separate

I'm wondering if I'm going about this wrong.  Here is my attempt at extracting all 3.

```
SELECT [City State Zip]
    ,CHARINDEX(',',[City State Zip]) AS [Comma location]
    ,SUBSTRING([City State Zip],CHARINDEX(',',[City State Zip]),13) AS [State and Zip]
    ,SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING([City State Zip],CHARINDEX(',',[City State Zip]),13),5,9)

-- Below code attempts to add a dash to the 9 digit zip codes but appears to only be doing it to some of them
    CASE LEN(SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING([City State Zip],CHARINDEX(',',[City State Zip]),13),5,9))
        WHEN 9
        THEN
            STUFF((SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING([City State Zip],CHARINDEX(',',[City State Zip]),13),5,9)
        ELSE
            (SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING([City State Zip],CHARINDEX(',',[City State Zip]),13),5,9)
        END AS Zip

    ,SUBSTRING([City State Zip],0,CHARINDEX(',',[City State Zip])) AS City

-- This code for extracting the STATE is producing an error "Invalid length parameter passed to the SUBSTRING function"
    ,SUBSTRING([City State Zip],CHARINDEX(',',[City State Zip])+1,LEN([City State Zip])- (CHARINDEX(',',[City State Zip])+1 + 5))

FROM dbo.foo
```

SO now how do I extract the State? Currently it fails with "Invalid length parameter passed to the SUBSTRING function"

The City will always be followed by a comma, and the state will always be 2 digits.

Sample data below:

Georgetown, DE 19947

Greenwood, DE 199502039

Dover, DE 19901

New Castle, DE 197205069

Lewes, DE 199581984

Newark, DE 197118734

Smyrna, DE 19904

Baltimore, MD 21020

Dover, DE 19901

Comment: On your sample data the cities are not folowed alvey by a coma:)

Comment: Thank you.  I've fixed the sample data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would break up your logic and use a query like this:

```
SELECT 
    [city],
    [state],
    CASE LEN([zip])
        WHEN 5 THEN [zip]
        WHEN 9 THEN STUFF([zip],6,0,'-')
    END [zip]
FROM (
    SELECT 
        LEFT([City State Zip],CHARINDEX(',',[City State Zip])-1) [city],
        SUBSTRING([City State Zip],CHARINDEX(',',[City State Zip])+2,2) [state],
        RIGHT([City State Zip],CHARINDEX(' ',REVERSE([City State Zip]))-1) [zip]
    FROM dbo.foo
) A
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved it, here is the working code to split out a column of City, State Zip into 3 separate in addition to adding dashes to the zip when it is 9 digits.

```
SELECT 

CASE LEN(SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING([City State Zip],CHARINDEX(',',[City State Zip]),13),5,9))
    WHEN 9
    THEN
        STUFF((SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING([City State Zip],CHARINDEX(',',[City State Zip]),13),5,9)
    ELSE
        (SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING([City State Zip],CHARINDEX(',',[City State Zip]),13),5,9)
    END AS Zip

,SUBSTRING([City State Zip],0,CHARINDEX(',',[City State Zip])) AS City
,SUBSTRING([City State Zip],CHARINDEX(',',[City State Zip])+1,4) AS STATE

FROM dbo.foo
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming state is always surrounded by spaces:

```
DECLARE @citystatezip VARCHAR(100)='Georgetown, DE 19947'

SELECT substring(@citystatezip,1,Charindex(',',@citystatezip,0)-1),
       LTRIM(RTRIM(substring(@citystatezip,Charindex(',',@citystatezip,0)+1,4))),
       substring(@citystatezip,Charindex(',',@citystatezip,0)+5,LEN(@citystatezip))
```